# How to find the Laplacian Eigen Values of the given graph

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, graph-laplacian

> Find the Laplacian eigen-values of the of the graph on $N$ vertices whose edge set is given by $\{(i,i+1),1\le i<n\}$ and the edge $(1,n)$ .

The answer is given to be $2-2\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$ .

**My try**:

I tried to proceed by induction.
For the case $n=3$ ;I got the matrix as $L$=
\begin{array}{cccc}
2& -1 &-1\\
-1& 2 &-1\\
-1 & -1 &2
\end{array}

I got the eigen values as $0,3,3$  which are nowhere near the given the eigen values.

How should I do it? Please give some ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Nowhere near? Are you sure?

Comment: Try finding the eigenvectors of this Laplacian first. If $v\in\mathbb C^n$ is an eigenvector, then $(2-\lambda)v_i=v_{i-1\bmod n}+v_{i+1\bmod n}$, i.e., for all $0\le i\le n$, the sum of $v_{i-1\bmod n}$ and $v_{i+1\bmod n}$ is parallel to $v_i$. Also, by symmetry the norms of all of the $v_i$ must be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Laplacian matrix of the cycle on $n$ vertices, given by
\begin{equation*}
L = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & - 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1& 2\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

$L$ is an example of a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix/). Any circulant matrix is fully determined by its first row $[a_0\ a_1\ \cdots\ a_{n-1}]$, and its eigenvalues are given by a [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues/). However, I will demonstrate the method of computation here (for the special case $L$).

Let $\omega = \exp\left( \dfrac{2i\pi}{n} \right)$, the primitive $n$-th root of unity, and let $v_1 = [1\ \omega\ \omega^2\ \cdots \omega^{n-1}]^T$. Then,
\begin{align*}
Lv_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
2 - \omega - \omega^{n-1}\\
2 \omega - \omega^2 - 1\\
2 \omega^2 - \omega^3 - \omega\\
\vdots\\
2\omega^{n-1} - 1 - \omega^{n-2}
\end{bmatrix} = (2 - \omega - \omega^{n-1})\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ \omega \\ \omega^2\\ \vdots\\ \omega^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
(keeping in mind that $\omega^n = 1$).

Thus, $2 - \omega - \omega^{n-1} = 2 - \omega - \omega^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $L$, with eigenvector $v_1$.

Similarly, for $k = 2, \cdots, n$, define $v_k = [1\ \omega^k\ \cdots\ \omega^{k(n-1)}]^T$, the vector obtained by taking the $k$-th power of each entry of $v_1$. Note that $v_n$ is the all-ones vector. Then, a computation exactly similar to the above one shows that $v_k$ is an eigenvector of $L$ for the eigenvalue $2 - \omega^k - \omega^{-k} = 2 - (\omega^k + \omega^{-k})$.

Simplifying, $\omega^k + \omega^{-k} = \exp\left( \dfrac{2ki\pi}{n} \right) + \exp\left( -\dfrac{2ki\pi}{n} \right) = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{2k\pi}{n} \right)$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $L$ are
\begin{align*}\large\boxed{
2 \left( 1 -  \cos \dfrac{2k\pi}{n} \right), \quad k = 1, 2, \ldots, n.}
\end{align*}

---

Alternatively, you can find the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ of the adjacency matrix $A$ (which is also circulant), and use the fact that $L = 2I - A$ to get the eigenvalues $2 - \lambda_k$ of $L$.

Comment: I got it now ;thank you very much

Comment: @learnmore Glad you got it. The same technique works for all circulant matrices, and is a very useful one to know if you work in graph theory and combinatorics. Also, these eigenvectors can be normalized by dividing by $\sqrt n$ (for all of them have that as their norm). Then, taking these normalized vectors as column vectors gives you the diagonalizing matrix for any circulant matrix. In other words, all circulant matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable — this proves that all circulant matrices commute with one another!

Comment: I am having one problem here :why are all diagonalizable matrices commuting?

Comment: if we take $A=$ \begin{array}{cc} 1& 2\\0&3 \end{array} and $B=$ \begin{array}{cc} 3 &2 \\0 & -1\end{array}\

Comment: @learnmore All *simultaneously* diagonalizable matrices commute. $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable if there exists a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = D_A$ (say) and $P^{-1}BP = D_B$ are both diagonal. Then $A = P D_A P^{-1}$ and $B = P D_B P^{-1}$ implies that $$AB = (P D_A P^{-1})(P D_B P^{-1}) = P D_A D_B P^{-1} = P D_B D_A P^{-1} = (P D_B P^{-1})(P D_A P^{-1}) = BA$$. Here, $D_A D_B = D_B D_A$ because both are diagonal matrices.

Comment: Sorry I missed the term *simultaneosly*

Comment: Do you work in spectral graph theory IIT Bhubaneshwar? Just asked you out of curiosity; Ignore if its personal

Comment: @learnmore No, I work at MIT Manipal. I'm working on graphs and groups (and other algebraic structures), but I've done some work in spectral graph theory.

Comment: What work did you do? I am just a starter here. So I was asking if you could give me some ways/hints/problems to work here.

Comment: @learnmore I've worked on the Laplacian spectrum (constructed a class of Laplacian integral graphs), and very recently, on the energy and spectra of a modified adjacency matrix (for studying domination). Also studied the "matrix product" of graphs. My real interest is group theory, though.

Comment: I think you have many problems to work on already. Find (or try to find) the adjacency and Laplacian spectra of the basic classes of graphs. That's the first step and gives you some hands-on experience and familiarity. Then (or in parallel), study general results related to graph spectra (interlacing, Courant-Fischer, spectra of circulant matrices etc.) and see which of these can be used to simplify the problems you already solved, as well as to solve the ones you couldn't before. Knowing and correctly using these general theorems is the only way to get really good, new results (in research).

Comment: Do you recommend any books in this subject?

Comment: @learnmore *Spectra of Graphs*, by Brouwer and Haemers, is comprehensive, and [freely available online](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/2WF02/spectra.pdf). But you might find it a bit sparse on explanation and examples. So I recommend *[Graphs and Matrices](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781447165682)*, by R.B. Bapat. Chapters 3 and 4 introduce the adjacency and Laplacian matrices and their spectra, with very nice examples. The results are also broken down into smaller results that can be studied and understood one at a time. Later chapters (6, 8, 9, 10) cover some more advanced results.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian is given by:

$$ L = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & -1 \\
                      -1 &  2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 \\
                       0 & -1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\
                       \vdots & & & \vdots & \\
                       -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

and indeed you have recovered the $n=3$ case. Observe that:
 $$\cos(2 \pi \cdot (0/3))=1, \, \cos(2\pi \cdot (1/3))=-1/2, \, \cos(2\pi \cdot (2/3))=-1/2 .$$

Comment: Thank you very much ;Can you please suggest how to proceed in general case

Comment: I think you can get a formula for the characteristic polynomial inductively by applying the cofactor expansion formula a few times. I think using this procedure the formula for the $n$th polynomial involves the $(n-1)$st,$(n-2)$nd, and $(n-3)$rd polynomials.