# How to find eigen values of the above matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

> How to find all the eigen values of the graph (Laplacian):

$G=(V(G),E(G))$ where $V(G)=\{1,2,\ldots n\}$ and $E(G)=\{(i,i+1):1\le i<n\}$

On finding the Laplacian Matrix of the graph I found that it is of the form:

$L$=

\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
1 & -1 &0 &0\ldots &0\\
-1 &2 &-1&0\ldots & 0\\
0 & -1 &2 &-1\ldots &0\\
\ldots &\ldots &\ldots \\
\ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
\ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
0 & \ldots &\ldots&\ldots   -1&1
\end{array}

The question now reduces in solving the characteristic polynomial of $L$
How should I proceed to find the eigen values from here?

It is impossible to solve the characteristic polynomial here?Please help.

Comment: One approach is to treat the $n$-vertex path graph $P_n$ as a quotient of the ring graph $R_{2n}$, which you studied in [a previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809210/265466). It may help to notice that this Laplacian is a discrete approximation to a vibrating string.

Comment: Why should I do it in that way? Why not the obvious way?

Comment: Because you’re not getting anywhere in the obvious way? ;) More seriously, because it’s an example of a generally applicable technique for analyzing graphs.

Comment: can you please explain in detail ;i am not getting what is meant by quotient  here

Answer (score 1):

Treat the path graph $P_n$ as a quotient of the ring graph $R_{2n}$ by identifying each node $(u)$ of $P_n$ with the pair of nodes $(u)$ and $(2n-1-u)$ of $R_{2n}$. You can visualize this by laying out $R_{2n}$ with its nodes in two parallel rows.

First, suppose that $w$ is an eigenvector of $L_{R_{2n}}$ with $w(u)=w(2n-1-u)$ for $0\le u\lt n$ and let $z=(w(0),\cdots,w(n-1))^T$. For $0<u<n-1$, $$\begin{align}
[L_{P_n}z](u) &= 2z(u)-\sum_{j\in N_{P_n}(u)}z(j) \\
&= 2w(u)-\sum_{j\in N_{R_{2n}}(u)}w(j) \\
&= \frac12\left(2w(u)-\sum_{j\in N_{R_{2n}}(u)}w(j)+2w(2n-1-u)-\sum_{j\in N_{R_{2n}}(2n-1-u)}w(j)\right) \\
&= \frac12\left([L_{R_{2n}}w](u)+[L_{R_{2n}}w](2n-1-u)\right) \\
&= \frac12\left(\lambda w(u)+\lambda w(2n-1-u)\right) \\
&= \lambda w(u) \\
&= \lambda z(u).
\end{align}$$ For $i=0$, $$\begin{align}[L_{P_n}z](0) &= z(0)-z(1) \\
&= 2z(0)-z(1)+z(0) \\
&= 2w(0)-w(1)+w(0) \\
&= 2w(0)-w(1)+w(2n-1) \\
&= \lambda w(0) \\
&= \lambda z(0)
\end{align}$$ and the other end is similar. Thus, $z$ is an eigenvector of $L_{P_n}$, with the same eigenvalue as $w$.

It remains to be shown that such eigenvectors exist. Let $v_k$ be the eigenvector of $L_{R_{2n}}$ generated by $\omega^k$ as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809410/265466), with eigenvalue $\lambda_k=2\left(1-\cos{k\pi\over n}\right)$. For $0\lt k\lt n$, observe that $\lambda_{2n-k}=\lambda_k$, so $v_{2n-k}$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda_k$. We seek scalars $a$ and $b$ such that $$av_k(u)+bv_{2n-k}(u)=av_k(2n-1-u)+bv_{2n-k}(2n-1-u)$$ for all $0\le u\lt n$. Since $v_{2n-k}(u)={\overline v}_k(u)$, this can be rewritten as $$a\left(v_k(u)-v_k(2n-1-u)\right)=b\left({\overline v}_k(2n-1-u)-{\overline v}_k(u)\right).$$ It is enough to examine the case $u=0$ as the other cases can be obtained from it by multiplying both sides of the equation by a scalar (by a positive real number, in fact): $$a\left(1-e^{ik(2n-1)\pi/n}\right)=b\left(e^{-ik(2n-1)\pi/n}-1\right) \\
a\left(1-e^{-ik\pi/n}\right)=b\left(e^{ik\pi/n}-1\right)$$ which has $a=\frac12e^{ik\pi/(2n)}$ and $b=\frac12e^{-ik\pi/(2n)}$ as a solution. So, $$w_k = \frac12e^{ik\pi/(2n)}v_k+\frac12e^{-ik\pi/(2n)}{\overline v}_k = \Re\left(e^{ik\pi/(2n)}v_k\right)$$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda_k$ with the required property. For $\lambda_0=0$, $v_0=\mathbf 1$ and the above formula yields $w_0=\mathbf 1$ as well. (You can also derive this eigenvector by finding a suitable linear combination of $\Re(v_k)$ and $\Im(v_k)$, which are also eigenvectors of $\lambda_k$. Plotting the elements of $v_k$ on the complex plane makes what’s going on here clearer—the sets of points are being rotated to vertically align $v_k(u)$ and $v_k(2n-u)$.)

So, the eigenvalues of the path graph $P_n$ are $$\lambda_k=2\left(1-\cos\frac{k\pi}{n}\right), \quad k=1,2,\ldots,n$$ with associated eigenvectors $$v_k(u)=\cos\left({\pi ku\over n}+{\pi k\over2n}\right).$$

Comment: One technique is given in the book 'Graphs and matrices' by R B Bapat ( theorem 3.7). It is given for the adjacency matrix case.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to find all the eigenvalues of the graph path Laplacian $L(P_n)$, but it is desirable you are familiar with Chebyschyov (Chebyshev, Tchebycheff) polynomials:

> **Definition $\boldsymbol{1}$ (Chebyschyov polynomials of the second kind).** These are defined by the recurrence relation \begin{align} U_0(x) &=1;\\ U_1(x)&=2x;\\ U_n(x)&=2x\,U_{n-1}(x)-U_{n-2}(x), \quad n\geq 2.\end{align}
>
> **Lemma $\boldsymbol{2}$ (sorted roots of $\boldsymbol{U_n(x)}$).**
>   $$x_k := -\cos \left(\frac{k}{n+1} \pi\right), \qquad 1\leq k \leq n.$$
>
> **Lemma $\boldsymbol{3}$ (Chebyschyov determinant).** Let $c\in\{-1,1\}$ so that $c^2=1$ and $c^m =c^{m\bmod 2}$. Then
>   $$U_n(x)\equiv \begin{vmatrix} 2x&c&0&\ldots&0&0&0\\ c&2x&c&\ldots&0&0&0\\ 0&c&2x&\ldots&0&0&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\ 0&0&0&\ldots&2x&c&0\\ 0&0&0&\ldots&c&2x&c\\ 0&0&0&\ldots&0&c&2x \end{vmatrix}_{(n\times n \text{ matrix})}.$$

The following works for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but I shall use $n=4$ because of space:  $$L(P_4)= \left[\begin{array}{r} 1&-1&0&0\\ -1&2&-1&0\\ 0&-1&2&-1\\ 0&0&-1&1 \end{array}\right].$$  Then the characteristic polynomial of $L(P_4)$ is (let $x:=\tfrac{\lambda-2}{2}$ so that $2x=\lambda-2$ and $2x+1=\lambda-1$):

$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4))= \begin{vmatrix} 2x+1&1&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1&2x+1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Expand conveniently along the first row:
$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4)) =\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1&2x+1 \end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1&2x+1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Expand the second determinant along the first row:
$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4)) =\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1&2x+1 \end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0\\ 1&2x&1\\ 0&1&2x+1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Expand each determinant conveniently along the last row:
$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4)) =\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1&2x \end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{vmatrix} \\ +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0\\ 1&2x&1\\ 0&1&2x \end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0\\ 1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Expand the second and fourth determinant along the last row:
$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4)) =\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0&0\\ 1&2x&1&0\\ 0&1&2x&1\\ 0&0&1&2x \end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0\\ 1&2x&1\\ 0&1&2x \end{vmatrix} \\ +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1&0\\ 1&2x&1\\ 0&1&2x \end{vmatrix} +\begin{vmatrix} 2x&1\\ 1&2x \end{vmatrix}$$

By Lemma $3$ we have:
$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4)) =U_4(x) +2\,U_3(x) +U_2(x).$$

By Definition $1$ we have that $U_4(x) +U_2(x) =2x\,U_3(x)$, so that
$$\det(\lambda I_4 -L(P_4)) =(2x+2)\,U_3(x) =\lambda\,U_3(\tfrac{\lambda-2}{2}).$$

And in general, for $n  \geq 2$:
$$\det(\lambda I_n -L(P_n)) =\lambda\,U_{n-1}(\tfrac{\lambda-2}{2}).$$

Then $\lambda_1=0$ is a root, and Lemma $2$ gives us the other $n-1$ roots: (beware the reindexing)
$$\lambda_k =2-2\cos\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\pi\right), \quad 2\leq k \leq n.$$

Coincidentally, the formula above also generates $\lambda_1$ for $k=1$. Simplifying ($1-\cos 2\theta=2\sin^2 \theta$):

> **Result (eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{L(P_n)}$).** $$\lambda_k := 4\sin^2\left(\frac{k-1}{n} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right), \quad 1\leq k \leq n.$$